# User suggesting his own app in an answer

Tags: discussion

Help/On-topic guidelines forbid "Marketing your Android app or doing market research".

Now, if a user is looking for a method or an app to check something on his device, retrieve a system parameter or just perform something on Android, is it ok for another user to suggest his own app - or an app by a developer he knows - in the answer when the app matches the needs of the question and there's no well known app doing the same job?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, absolutely — even if there are other alternatives, as long as it is relevant.  Just **clearly disclose that it is your app**, and then otherwise treat it the same as you would treat an answer about someone else's app: link to it and explain how and why it solves the user's problem.

Comment: I'd like to add to what Matthew has said that the reason for the disclosure rule is so that visitors to the site have all the information available, so they can judge the value of each recommendation.  You might interpret an answer "I've used this app for years and it's great" differently from "I work for this company's marketing department and you should buy the app". "Astro-turfing" (posting adverts as if they were genuine recommendations) devalues all recommendations.

Comment: @Dan Hulme I was mostly thinking about free apps, but I understand what you mean.

Comment: All of that said, if the user has a recommendation for his app in most or all of his answers, that's undesirable.